# Long delay when doing $rootscope.$on with large object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

In AngularJS I have a js object (factory) with lots of functions. 4000 lines. When I pull in the data from php and create the object it takes pretty quick.

```
$http.get('pivots/list.php')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.listOfPivots = data;
                  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.listOfPivots.length; i++ ) {
                    pivot = new pivotFactory($scope.listOfPivots[i]);
```

Then I need to share the selected object with other controllers.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("Update", pivot);
```

When I get the selected object there's a pause of a few seconds.

```
$rootScope.$on("Update", function(event, p) {
       $scope.selectedPivot = p;
});
```

How can I measure this timeout out to show a progress bar or what can I do to prevent this long delay?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emit and broadcast, you can simply assign variable to value as
`$rootScope.selectedpivot=pivot` so that that value is available in another controllers too.This will avoid timeout

Eg: $rootScope.data=10 is assigned in one controller.In another controller if you try console.log($rootScope.data), you'll get value 10.

Comment: thanks @gayathri that has helped me clean up my code a lot and helped with speed a bit. I do see now that there's a pause when I assign a new factory object to my $rootScope like this: $rootScope.selectedPivot = new pivotFactory($scope.masterListOfPivots[$scope.selectedPivotR‌​ow]); Like I mentioned my factory is about 4000lines long. Do you know why that might happen and can I show feedback?

Comment: The backend is taking time to complete to complete its execution and give you the value via http. What you need to do is, give <img ng-src="load.gif" ng-show="loading"></img> . Before $http.get ,assign $scope.loading=true so load buffer keeps appearing. And after $http.get , assign $scope.loading=false. Idea is, until backend completes its execution, have a load buffer till backend has completed it all and fetched the data to http. Only then process will be synchronous. Hope you understand. 
I don't get what do you mean by feedback.